# Half fixed, half scrollable layout that can be scrolled

Tags: html, css

I have an exotic design that needs the following. The left side must scroll, while the right side + top head must stay put (fixed). See attached image.

I can accomplish this by position: fixed on the top and right side. The top & right hand side stays put while the left scrolls.... **BUT then the PROBLEM is that there is NO scroll bar anymore if anybody zooms in and you also cannot scroll left to right to see whole page**

How would one attack such a layout?

Could not post code before - let me try again:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Exotic</title>


<style type="text/css">
#top {
background-color: #FF0;
width: 1800px;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

#sideLeft {
float: left;
width: 950px;
background-color: #9C0;
clear: left;
}

#sidebarLeft {
background-color: #0CC;
height: 800px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}

.list {
float: left;
width: 600px;
margin-top: 100px;
}
#ordoner {
background-color: #F90;
float: left;
width: 640px;
height: 800px;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 950px;
}

#sidebarRight {
width: 210px;
height: 800px;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 1590px;
background-color: #0CF;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="sideLeft">
  <div id="sidebarLeft"><!--end #sidebarLeft--></div>
  <div class="list"><!--end .lisist--></div>
<!--end #sideLeft--></div>
<div id="ordoner"><!--end #ordoner--></div>
<div id="sidebarRight"><!--end #sidebarRight--></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Clarification:**
My css reflects 2 things in the right hand side but the point is that the right and the top should be static while the left scrolls... AND they should be horizontally scrollable IF a user zooms :)

Also, I've tried wrapping things in a container div, but that has its own problems - it scrolls but never reaches the right hand side if the window is not maximized.

Thanks again.

**To clarify: As an example to get my point across... please resize the stackoverflow window to half your horizontal screen size... Now see how you can scroll left to right? If you zoom in, you can scroll left to right also to see the whole page. Well, in my layout, which works in full screen browser mode... once I resize that scroll bar at the bottom does not appear at all leaving the user with no ability to scroll horizontally. See picture below**

**Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/moby7000/tWb3e/**

[image]

[image]

**[image: New picture of layout with more detail:]**

Answer (score 18):

It's not very hard to create a layout like this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.Container {
  height: 100%;
}

.Container:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.Header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #6ea364;
}

.Content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Content:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.Wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper>div {
  height: 100%;
}

.LeftContent {
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}

.RightContent {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header">
    <p>The Header div height is not fixed (But it can be if you want it to)</p>
    <p>This Layout has been tested on: IE10, IE9, IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. using Pure CSS 2.1 only</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Content">
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <div class="RightContent">
        <p>You can fix the width of this content.</p>
        <p>If you want, its width will stretch just as it needs to.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="LeftContent">
        <p>this will scroll</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bonus:**
With a little change in the CSS you can create a beautiful scrolling.
See that [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QMsuD/1/)

If you want to set a width value to the left side, that is actually bigger then the body size (and to have an horizontal scroll), do it [that](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QMsuD/2/) way.

```
<div class="LeftContent">
    <div style="width:1200px;"> <-- better to aplly the width from the CSS
        ..<The content>..
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi... thank you for the help. This however does not solve my issue. All this does is make it fluid but it does not solve the left to right scroll (see my OP). Also, once .leftContent is set to a fixed width (I set it 1200px) it completely disappears (jumps) when window is resized. I could not connect to jfiddle but I pasted all content in a page in wamp.

Comment: Please see my answer to user1876542 below as it clarifies things a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Hello avrahamcool. Sorry, this is probably a bit my fault as it's a very hard issue to explain into words. I wish stackoverflow would allow images in the replies. So I need the layout to stay fixed. width and all.... I don't need to scroll within a div but rather the whole page... So the purple .leftContent should not be scrollable within itself. There should be only 2 scrollbars, top and bottom... The bottom should only appear when the user zooms in or window is resized and he needs to scroll left to right. I don't really want content to be clipped within a div. I've updated my OP to clarify.

Comment: To further clarify... there should be one right hand scroll bar at the windows edge, not within content. Same for bottom (horizontal scroll) which should appear when window is resized or zoomed in. At no point should content be fluid or hidden within a div. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completely. but from what I understood, you need to fix the `body` width. because right now, when you resize the window, the body always take the viewport width and the content needs to shrink to fit in. but if you specify a `width` or a `min-width` to the body, it will add a scrollbar when you resize to something smaller

Comment: Lol... I'm doing a horrible job of explaining myself. So my layout I've gotten to work in maximized browser window. BUT if I resize to let's say half the horizontal width, I have NO horizontal scroll bar to navigate to the content's left side. Same with zooming. The layout I have is fixed, there is no fluid stuff going on. When the user zooms in or resizes they should be able to scroll to the left to see whatever is off browser screen. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it does. and for that, you can specify the `body` width. as I explained in my former comment. it will do the trick.

Comment: Tried it.... but now it separates... try resizing your browser window to 55%. Now try and reach the blue sidebar on the right hand side?? :) You can't... it doesn't scroll. Unless I'm missing something. PS: don't think you'll be able to see this effect on JSfiddle as it's not a full sized browser window.

Comment: I really don't see the problem in my machine.. please edit your question, post your latest code (preferably in a fiddle), and add some images to clarify what the problem is. and what do you actually want. we'll find you a solution.

Comment: Just posted a new image of the problem. The code is the one that is posted. Thank you for all the help :) !!!

Comment: The whole thing is not build correctly.. fixed elements, with floating ones, and everything overlaps.. that not the way to do it. start with a correct layout, like the one I gave you, read it carefully to understand how it works, then change it and add the specifications you need.

Comment: Thank you but your layout is fluid. How would you get it to behave like what I need? If I give it fixed width it doesn't work anymore. Also, it does things that I'm not looking to do, like scrolling within div. Sorry for being dim but how would it apply to what I am looking for. It seems to go in a totally different direction.

Comment: so lets retake it from the beginning. can you provide an updated image (with the real sizes) of the layout you want?

Comment: Ok, done... Please take a look at bottom of my OP. Much clearer I think. Everything (.container) should be 1800px and all is fixed width. Thank you.

Comment: when you say that left is scrollable, do you mean that it has is own scrollbar? or that the main scrollbar should only make the left side move?

Comment: The main scroll bar should make left side move. So the normal scroll bar that is on the right hand side of every page should move it. There should be no 'internal' scroll bars.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use a script to make the right side ignore the scroll. you cant use fixed position, because then the right side will be positioned relatively to the view port. (this is what causing you problems when resizing). my advice to you: make the left side have is own scrollbar, but it will be from his left side.. so it not be ugly. then you don't need any fixed positioned, or any script. I'll demonstrate in a fiddle if you want..

Comment: First - thank you so much for all the help and thanks for confirming what I suspected... there's no way to do this in pure css outside of what you describe. Problem is client doesn't want internal scrolls, and for good reason - people that use the site will be older and internal scrolls confuse them. So this seems to me to be a javascript option? Would creating a div that scrolls under the right hand side divs (just as a place holder) do anything?

Comment: [Here is a fiddle with my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dtWWA/). if you want to tweak your HTML, you can have a div to take the place, as you said.. you will have to use `position:absolute` on the right div and make him appear at the place you want. then change is z-index to be above everything else it should work if you do it right. but it will be hard to manage, if you need to change the layout some day.. even if it a simple change like enlarging the content..

Comment: my fiddle (in the comment above) look like it doesn't have an internal scroll, and his layout is simple and very easy to understand and manage. copy it to your local machine to see it in action..

Comment: If we could move the scroll bar to the right, where it normally belongs, your layout would be PERFECT!... Is there a way?

Comment: only by tweaking the HTML. make the left side to have 100% width (so his scroll would appear at the end, like normal), but within it, to have another container with 950px (like you wanted) so the content of the left bar will not go under the right one. then make the right one `position:absolute`, with `top` value that match the header height, and left value of `950px` (so it will not overlap the left bar), but make it a little smaller then `850px`, so it will not overlap the scroller.. I really **don't** like that kind of layout.. but if you must..

Comment: I agree with you... it is clunky and not elegant code... but I'll give it a go since I cannot seem to find the answer withing 'normal' css :(

Comment: I believe the idea is to keep the parent container `position: absolute; height: 100%` and give the scrollable div `overflow: scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `overflow:auto;` to the area you want to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

in body?

Comment: Just tried it right now but it does nothing new. However from my original op you'll note that I probably need an overflow-x as that is the problem. So I tried that too.... All it does is put an empty scroll bar at the bottom. I think it may be my fault for not being more clear - For example: Resize the stackoverflow window to half your horizontal screen size... Now see how you can scroll left to right? If you zoom in, you can scroll left to right also to see the whole page. Well, in my layout, which works in full screen browser mode... once I resize that bar at the bottom disappears.