# Trying to use css to have top div scrollable and bottom div fixed and not scrollable

Tags: html, css

I want a scrollable top/main/content section that if it's content is too large will scroll, with a smaller fixed size section at the bottom. It can't scroll out of view.

Started building off a post i found off  [Half fixed, half scrollable layout that can be scrolled... CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056012/half-fixed-half-scrollable-layout-that-can-be-scrolled-css)

I've converted it to be much closer to what I want here..   https://jsfiddle.net/caseycupp/vp8pnstt/5/

```
<div class="Container">
<div class="Header">
<div class="HWrapper">
  <div class="HInsideContent">
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
    <p> header </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Content">
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="InsideContent">
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>
    <p>this will scroll</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
      * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.Container {
  height: 100%;
}

.Container:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.Header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 150px;
}

.Content {
  position: relative;
}

.Content:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.Header:before {
  /*content: '';
clear: both;
display: block;*/
}

.Wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.HWrapper {
  /* position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
*/
}

.InsideContent {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}

.HInsideContent {
  /*height: 100%;  
background-color: yellow;
overflow: auto;
}*/
```

But I just can't quite get it to flip/reverse. (scrollable top section) fixed size footer underneath)

[Trying to flip this sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWvII.jpg)